# How can I make json that has array on ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'd like to make json that include array as follows. I prepared a product model that has the following columns and tried to make json by to_json function. However, it cannot make asset_ids array. Could you tell me how to achieve this kind of json?

**prefered json**

```
{
  "asset_ids": [
    "<base 58 asset id>"
  ],
  "name_short": "<string>",
  "name": "<string>",
  "contract_url": "<url>",
  "issuer": "<string>",
  "description": "<string>",
  "description_mime": "<mime type>",
  "type": "<string>",
  "divisibility": <integer>,
  "link_to_website": <boolean>,
  "icon_url": "<url>",
  "image_url": "<url>",
  "version": "<string>"
}
```

**product model**

```
 id: nil,
 asset_ids: nil,
 name: nil,
 name_short: nil,
 contact_url: nil,
 issuer: nil,
 description: nil,
 description_mime: nil,
 type: nil,
 divisibility: nil,
 link_to_website: nil,
 icon_url: nil,
 image_url: nil,
 version: nil>
```

**json made of product model**

```
{"id":null,
 "asset_ids":null,
 "name":null,
 "name_short":null,
 "contact_url":null,
 "issuer":null,
 "description":null,
 "description_mime":null,
 "type": null,
 "divisibility":null,
 "link_to_website":null,
 "icon_url":null,
 "image_url":null,
 "version":null
}
```

Comment: what is your desired output? also can you share how are you creating that json?

Comment: Plz wait for a minuite. However, your answer(you've already deleted) is enough for me.

Comment: I only want to know that how to make json including array from model.

Comment: I got confused reading your question the second time and hence deleted my answer. Thanks for making it clear, I have undeleted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON can have arrays. Here's an example:

```
require 'json'
hash = {"a" => [1,2,3,4], "b" => "val"}
puts hash.to_json
# {"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":"val"}
```